# VBA to HTML, Hidden Input ID

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I managed to create a simple script that takes excel input and fills a web form.

Everything works amazingly with the following code:

```vb
Sub Autofill()
    Dim IE As Object    
    Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
    
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://share.amazon.com/sites/IPV/Lists/IPV%20Appeals%20tracker/NewForm.aspx?Source=https%3A%2F%2Fshare%2Eamazon%2Ecom%2Fsites%2FIPV%2FLists%2FIPV%2520Appeals%2520tracker%2FAllItems%2Easpx&RootFolder="
    
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    
    IE.document.getElementById("Title_fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247_$TextField").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("AB2")
    IE.document.getElementById("Seller_x0020_ID_2b32b5fa-ace8-44d5-bba5-5c0e321671ed_$TextField").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("E2")
    IE.document.getElementById("Country_65ced3ab-75bf-4553-9f05-de886924e70b_$DropDownChoice").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("B2")
    IE.document.getElementById("Inv_x0020_Date_5dbe2856-41fb-4aef-855a-8dbbe6de11a2_$DateTimeFieldDate").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("AC2")
    IE.document.getElementById("Associate_x0020_Action_531eade2-6a1d-42d1-9d2a-fc6d3e0c4af7_$DropDownChoice").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("J2")
    IE.document.getElementById("Correct_x0020_Associate_x0020_Ac_a9544f81-7d7e-4b15-b296-9face63d64e7_$DropDownChoice").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("K2")
    IE.document.getElementById("SIV_x0020_Action_0f88f118-1664-4e5e-be08-5a5f32462936_$DropDownChoice").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("T2")
    IE.document.getElementById("Correct_x0020_SIV_x0020_Action_c8b6acb1-95db-4341-8d08-03b67460e36e_$DropDownChoice").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("U2")
    IE.document.getElementById("Metric_9e0d1003-9726-4257-80b3-12e39713671d_$DropDownChoice").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("P2")
    IE.document.getElementById("Site_04f27633-b5f4-4604-81a5-ba431ff7fbcd_$DropDownChoice").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("A5")
    IE.document.getElementById("Category_6df9bd52-550e-4a30-bc31-a4366832a87d_$DropDownChoice").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("C5")
    IE.document.getElementById("SIV_x0020_RFI_x002f_RFD_x0020_re_d2e21853-8e6e-448a-9e64-fb50cc4bd58a_$DropDownChoice").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("W2")
    
    
    
    If InStr(1, (Range("Z2").Value), "No") > 0 Then IE.document.all.Item("Data_x0020_Correctly_x0020_Captu_1c33ffd0-1bf4-48d9-8ae3-c7fe4e349f4b_$RadioButtonChoiceField1").Checked = True
    
    IE.document.all.Item("Scored_x0020_by_x003a__a5e5d0db-1090-42e1-8fff-fd9ff0dec3d0_$RadioButtonChoiceField0").Checked = True
    IE.document.all.Item("Reversal_x0020_action_x0020_requ_c467e268-fde1-46c8-8f59-2e5e8d1eca2a_$RadioButtonChoiceField1").Checked = True
    
    
    
    IE.document.getElementById("Inv_Login_aabe5556-9387-4868-a07c-6a171ec5ed91_$ClientPeoplePicker_EditorInput").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("C2")
    IE.document.getElementById("Mgr_Login_382bcf2b-9082-42ff-9e73-6f9e45091581_$ClientPeoplePicker_EditorInput").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("B5")
    
    
    IE.document.getElementById("Comments_fafc7954-eb53-4f71-9f39-b1bf295b95d2_$TextField_inplacerte_label").innerText = "value" = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("O2")
   
End Sub
```

There is just one section(a text box for comments) that for some reason it wouldn't fill.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I tried to use this:

```vb
IE.document.getElementById("Inv_Login_aabe5556-9387-4868-a07c-6a171ec5ed91_$ClientPeoplePicker_EditorInput").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("C2")
```

Maybe this has to do with it being a Div? and for that reason I can't access its ID? I was thinking that maybe I wasnt suppose to use `IE.document.getElementById`.

Or I saw there whilst opening one of the spans, there was a hidden Input ID? maybe im suppose to access that Hidden ID input?

Please help

Comment: If it is a `div` it has no `.Value` but an `.innerHTML`.

Comment: You legend! Thank you very much, you should put it as an answer so i can marked it solved

Comment: Posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a `div` it has no `.Value` but an `.innerHTML` to change its content.